# std::cin не считывает пробел

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, cin, std

Делаю консольного бота, который принимает строку и с помощью regex ищет ее в моей "искусственной базе данных db.meb" (обычный txt можно сказать)... Заметил, что если я ввожу в answer какое-то слово и в конце ставлю пробел, то он не сохраняется в std::string answer, получается что и слово он не находит в db.meb.. Как это исправить?

```
std::string answer;

cin >> answer;

std::ifstream receive("db.meb");
if(receive.is_open())
{
    std::regex reg("([\\w\\s]{0,1024})" "(:)" "([\\w\\s]{0,1024})");
    std::cmatch cm;
    std::string buffer;

    while(getline(receive, buffer))
    {
        //getline(receive, buffer)
        if(std::regex_match(buffer.c_str(), cm, reg))
        {
            if(answer.find(cm[1]) != std::string::npos)
            {
                cout << cm[3];
            }
        }
    }
    // PERFECTLY WORKS)
}
```

Также я пробовал смотреть выражения с пробелами, на которые ответ мне не возвращается..

Структура db.meb:

```
got it:yepp
Hello:Hi
How are you:Fine
Hey :hello
```

Hello:Hi - works, Hey :hello - doesnt work, How are you:Fine - doesnt work
Спасибо заранее за помощь

Comment: Работать через `getline()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302996/changing-the-delimiter-for-cin-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы выбрали неподходящий способ. Для типа `std::string` определена перегрузка оператора `>>`, и выражение `cin >> answer` приводит к вызову функции [`operator<<,>> (std::basic_string)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt). Данная функция будет считывать данные, пока не встретит какой-либо пробельный символ (этот пробел остается во входном потоке).

Вместо этого вы можете использовать функцию [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), которая считывает данные до некоторого разделителя. По умолчанию разделителем является символ новой строки, что как раз вам подходит:

```cpp
std::string answer;
std::getline(std::cin, answer);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

советую сделать через `getline`: подключить библиотеку `<iostream>`, и написать после библиотеки:

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]